# TCP function recv() does not works in loop

Tags: c, linux, tcp

I am using infinite while loop to receive data from TCP server
I need to perform other task in loop simultaneously having higher priority
But control holds to `recv()` function every time it waits for TCP data.

```
while(1)
{
        rdlen = read(fd1, buf, (sizeof(buf) - 1));
        if (rdlen > 0) 
        {
            buf[rdlen] = 0;
            printf("%s",buf);
            memset(buf, 0, strlen(buf));
        }
        if((numbytes=recv(sockfd, buf1, wGetLen, 0)) != -1)
        {
            printf("%s %d\n", buf1, numbytes);
            memset(buf1, 0, strlen(buf1));                                
        }
}
```

How can I perform above operation without waiting for TCP to receive data?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15108122/recv-with-non-blocking-socket

Comment: Put the socket in non-blocking mode, and / or use `select()`, `poll()`, or similar to determine whether there is data available before you try to read from the socket.

Comment: Cargo-cult programming : `memset(buf1, 0, strlen(buf1));` This is dangerous nonsense, IMHO

Comment: ^^^ what @wildplasser says.  At best, such 'clear the buffer' operations are a waste of cycles, at worst, disastrous.  If strlen() is involved anywhere, then the scales tip heavily towards the dark side:(

Comment: Thread off the recv() loop?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [recv with non-blocking socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15108122/recv-with-non-blocking-socket)

Answer (score 2):

You need to set up the socket as a non-blocking socket.  In doing so, if you call `recv` and there is nothing to be received, the function call will return -1 to indicate an error with `EAGAIN` as the error code.

You can set the non-blocking flag as follows

```
int fdflag;
if ((fdflag = fcntl(sockfd, F_GETFL)) == -1) {
    perror("Error getting socket descriptor flags");
    exit(1);
}
fdflag |= O_NONBLOCK;
if (fcntl(sockfd, F_SETFL, fdflag) == -1) {
    perror("Error setting non-blocking option");
    exit(1);
}
```

Then you can change your `recv` call as follows:

```
     if((numbytes=recv(sockfd, buf1, wGetLen, 0)) != -1)
     {
         printf("%s %d\n",buf1,numbytes);
         memset(buf1, 0, sizeof(buf1));                                
     }
     else if (errno == EAGAIN)
     {
         printf("no data to receive\n");
     }
     else
     {
         perror("error on recv");
     }
```

Comment: Yes using above able to do other operation simultaneously but if data is available to recieve. " buf1" is showing empty.